# Keep latest file and move older files to a folder using UNIX Shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have many files (`File Format: ABC_YYYYMMDD.TXT`) in my folder.

```
- ABC_20150101.TXT 
- ABC_20150201.TXT 
- ABC_20150301.TXT 
- ABC_20150501.TXT
```

I need output as below.

```
- ABC_20150101.TXT - Moved to a folder name ARCHV in current path.
- ABC_20150201.TXT - Moved to a folder name ARCHV in current path.
- ABC_20150301.TXT - Moved to a folder name ARCHV in current path.
- ABC_20150501.TXT - Kept in the current path, since it is latest.
```

That is latest file kept in the current folder itself. But other files will be moved to another folder in the present working directory named `/ARCHV`.
Please let me know the `UNIX` statement do the task.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick solution, which relies on some installed programs:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname 'ABC*.TXT' -printf '%T@|%p\n' | sort -r -n | tail -n +2 | cut -d'|' -f2 | xargs -i mv {} ARCHV
```

- `find` prints the filenames with a preceeding unix timestamp
- `sort` sorts them by timestamp
- `tail` removes the first (most recent file)
- `cut` takes the filenames only (removes the timestamp)
- `xargs mv` moves the files

Comment: I think you need to add `-r` flag to `sort` right? Or you will be moving all the latest (leaving the oldest) files to ARCHV?

Comment: @Manuel: I appreciate your effort. But the code giving me some errors. Will this code works with Korn Shell?

Comment: @Manuel: I have changed code as below and the error has gone. `find ABC*.TXT | sort -r -n | tail +2 | cut -d'|' -f2 | xargs -i mv {} ARCHV` Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 2):

quick and dirty:

```
ls -1|awk 'p{printf "mv %s /archive\n",$0}{p=$0}'|sh
```

- test this line under the directory containting those `ABC_....` files
- `ls` without any sorting options will sort the list by name.
- pipe the result to the awk, skip the last line (file)
- remove the ending `|sh` will see the output generated by the command. If everything is ok, add the `|sh` will make those commands get executed
- I see your example file name doesn't have spaces. If they do contain spaces, change the `mv %s` into `mv \"%s\"`
- The target archive in my one-liner was named as `/archive`, you can change it into the right one.

Comment: 'p{printf ..}' - what will that p in front will do?

Comment: @Sadhun in short: `if p is not empty`